# Understanding associativity of the Monad's bind operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, bind, monads, operator-precedence

I was trying to understanding how the Monad's bind operator works, but found an example which was odd, because the apparent associativity didn't make sense to me considering the fact that `>>=` is *left*-associative. Here is the example, testing at an interpreter's prompt:

```
> Just 3 >>= \x -> Just "!" >>= \y -> Just (show x ++ y)
Just "3!"

> Just 3 >>= (\x -> Just "!" >>= (\y -> Just (show x ++ y)))
Just "3!"

> (Just 3 >>= \x -> Just "!" )>>= \y -> Just (show x ++ y)
<interactive>:3:50: error: Variable not in scope: x :: ()
```

I don't understand it because the second example runs in opposition to the third, because it seems that it goes in the way which is contradictory to the known associativity. I know that I am missing something, but I don't know what.

Comment: It binds `infixl`, so as the second expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the maximal munch rule, lambdas are parsed as far to the right as possible, so the left associativity of the `>>=` operator doesn't have a chance to come into play. It is your second snippet that the first is parsed as, not the third (which of course is an invalid code).

Comment: That is nice, I had no idea. That means that lambdas will always be able to override operator precedence ?

Comment: precedence only comes into play later. first the lambdas are read as far to the right as possible while it doesn't create syntactically wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the parenthesis take `x` out of scope:

```
(Just 3 >>= \x -> Just "!" ) >>= \y -> Just (show x ++ y)
```

`(Just 3 >>= \x -> Just "!" )` will become `Just "!"`, and `x` will go out out of scope.